# getParam a nested std::map

Tags: ros, roscpp, getparam, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a node that will read a YAML file (loaded from roslaunch) with the following structure:

```
home:
  1:
    "x": 0.0
    "y": 0.0
    "z": 0.0
    "qx": 0.0
    "qy": 0.0
    "qz": 0.0
    "qw": 0.0
  2:
    "x": 0.0
    "y": 0.0
    "z": 0.0
    "qx": 0.0
    "qy": 0.0
    "qz": 0.0
    "qw": 0.0
```

This is the relevant code on the node side:

```
class RouteParserNode
{
    public:
        RouteParserNode() :
            nh_private_("~")
        {
            nh_private_.getParam("home", route_home);
        };
        ~RouteParserNode();
     private:
        std::map<int, std::map<std::string, double>> route_home;
        ros::NodeHandle nh_private_;
};
```

However, the above node cannot be compiled and gives the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::getParam(const char 
[5], std::map<int, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, double> >&)’
             nh_private_.getParam("home", route_home);
```

which I assume is because getParam does not work for nested std::maps.

I am currently on ROS Indigo.

Is there a workaround for this, or another way for me to parse the file? My ultimate goal is to supply a list of goals (geometry_msgs/PoseStamped, but only primitive types were allowed for the std::map method hence the above yaml structure).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266012/getparam-a-nested-std::map/) by [rook](https://answers.ros.org/users/30711/rook/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-07-11**:
#q197304 is very similar but the answer doesn't provide a good code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For C++ there is an answer involving XmlRpc that #q197304 suggests, I used #q189299 as a starting point:

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue list1;
nh.getParam("/home", list1);
for(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::ValueStruct::const_iterator it = list1.begin();
    it != list1.end(); ++it)
{ 
  ROS_INFO_STREAM(it->first);
  XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue list2 = it->second;
  for(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::ValueStruct::const_iterator it2 = list2.begin();
      it2 != list2.end(); ++it2)
  { 
    XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue xml_rpc_value = it2->second;
    if (xml_rpc_value.getType() != XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeDouble)
      continue;

    const double value = static_cast<double>(xml_rpc_value);
    ROS_INFO_STREAM(it2->first << " " << value);
  }
}
```

What is maybe less efficient but uses more familiar standard C++ string operations instead of xmlrpc is to use getParamNames to get **all** the parameters then search through them for the tree you want ('home') and populate your map of maps manually.

```
  std::vector<std::string> keys;
  nh.getParamNames(keys);

  // or provide via param, or ros::this_node::getNamespace();
  std::string base_namespace = "/home";   // don't forget the leading slash

  ROS_INFO_STREAM(ns);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < keys.size(); ++i)
  {
    ... if keys[i] doesn't have a substring match of base_namespace then continue
    ... remove base_namespace from keys[i]
    ... split keys[i] into a vector of strings using '/' as a delimiter
    ... test if there are more or less split keys than expected (!= 3)
    // populate the nested maps 
    ... create route_home[split_keys[0]] if it doesn't already exist, then
    route_home[split_keys[0]][split_keys[1]] = split_keys[2];
  }
```

I get "ERROR: YAML dictionaries must have string keys" so I have to use `"1"` and `"2"` instead of `1` and `2` for keys for your example.

It would be nice if there was a nh.getParamNames(keys, "/foo"); and it would only get the params under '/foo'.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-11**:
To add to this: you might take a look at [rosparam_shortcuts](https://github.com/davetcoleman/rosparam_shortcuts) by Dave Coleman. It includes functionality similar to this.

See the [api doc](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/rosparam_shortcuts/html/namespacerosparam__shortcuts.html) fi.